# Не могу установить пакет Extended WPF Toolkit

Tags: wpf

Как установить данный пакет себе на Visual Studio 2017 Community? Я пробовал через NuGet в поиске найти название пакета и установить и писал в консоле NuGet нужную команду. Ничего не получилось. Вот что мне написала консоль (внизу текст).

PM> Install-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit

Выполняется попытка собрать информацию о зависимостях для пакета "Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.3.2.0" по отношению к проекту "Library", нацеленному на ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1".
Сбор данных о зависимостях занял 2,63 ms
Выполняется попытка разрешить зависимости для пакета «Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.3.2.0» с использованием DependencyBehavior «Lowest»
Обнаружено одно неразрешенное ограничение зависимостей пакетов (или несколько) в существующем файле packages.config. Все ограничения зависимостей должны быть разрешены, чтобы добавить или обновить пакеты. Если эти пакеты обновляются, это сообщение можно пропустить, если же нет, следующие ошибки могут блокировать текущую операцию с пакетами: 'EntityFramework.ru 6.1.3 ограничение: EntityFramework (= 6.1.3)'
Install-Package : Не удается разрешить зависимости. «EntityFramework 6.2.0» не совместима с 'EntityFramework.ru 6.1.3 ограничение: EntityFramework (= 6.1.3)'.
строка:1 знак:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Extended.Wpf.Toolkit
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

P.S. Обновил информацию данного вопроса. Файл packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.ru" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Ну и исходя из текста в этом файле, у меня в папке packages есть те самые две папки: EntityFramework.6.2.0 и EntityFramework.ru.6.1.3.

Comment: какие еще пакеты установлены?

Comment: Ну если рассматривать другие сторонние пакеты, то я ставил Entity Framework, самый последней версии, который был в NuGet.

Comment: Кроме EF что-то ставили? Добавьте в вопрос информацию из файла `packages.config`.

Comment: У `Extended.Wpf.Toolkit` нет зависимостей от `EF`, попытался воспроизвести у себя - оба пакета поставились без конфликтов.

Comment: Обновил текст своего вопроса.

Comment: Вам нужно обновить версию для пакета с русскоязычными сборками дополнений для Entity Framework `Install-Package EntityFramework.ru -Version 6.2.0/`

Comment: Получилось, не возникло никаких конфликтов. Есть к вам один вопрос, если вдруг знаете на него ответ. Скажите, пожалуйста, а где можно посмотреть гайд, вики и т.п. по подключению этой библиотеки в свой проект (я новичок в WPF, много чего не понимаю)? Имеется в виду, как это делается на стороне кода XAML и на стороне кода C#. В XAML вроде как так делается: в теге Windows я задал такую строку — xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" , а чтобы выбрать графический компонент из этого пакета, у меня получилось так сделать — <xctk:DateTimeUpDown Grid.Column="1"></xctk:DateTimeUpDown>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72760/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-cuurjol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конфликт версий произошел на предыдущем этапе. Неважно какой пакет устанавливать - он может быть добавлен только если не будет противоречий.

В данном случае проблема была с пакетом [EntityFramework.ru](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.ru/) у которого в зависимостях был EF другой версии.

Перед тем как установить пакет посмотрите на его зависимости - они автоматически загрузятся и вам не нужно будет ставить их по отдельности. Заодно минимизируется риск получить конфликт ограничений

---

`NuGet` не единственный менеджер пакетов есть и другие со своими преимуществам и недостатками. Оставлю ссылку на [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) который тоже часто используют.